# React.js: shouldComponentUpdate in array of stateless child Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent React class (`<EventList />`) that contains an object that store's it's Child Component's (`<Event />`) data. I've omitted many of the functions for the sake of brevity.

#### Background on the State of the `EventList`

```
/**
 * The events state looks like this before the EventList component is rendered:
 *
 * var events = {
 *      1: {
 *          id: 1,
 *          title: "Some title"
 *      },
 *      2: {
 *          id: 2,
 *          title: "Some other title"
 *      },
 *
 *      ...
 * };
 */
```

#### Event.jsx

```
var Event = React.createClass({

    /**
     * Pass up the ID of the Event and the new value of the Event's Title
     */
    _handleChange: function (e) {
        this.props.handleChange(this.props.id, e.target.value);
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="event">
                <input type="text" value={this.props.title} onChange={this._handleChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

#### EventList.jsx

```
var EventList = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        events: React.PropTypes.object
    },


    /**
     * Update the State of an event who's title has changed
     */
    _handleChange: function (id, title) {
        var newState = React.addons.update(this.state.events[id].title, {
            $set: title
        });

        this.setState(newState);
    },

    render: function () {

        var renderedEvents = Object.keys(this.state.events).map(function (id) {
            var event = this.state.events[id];
            return <Event key={event.id} title={event.title} handleChange={this._handleChange}/>;
        }, this);

        return (
            <div className="events">
                {renderedEvents}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Now this is fine, and it works. The state of the title gets updated and everything renders and re-renders successfully; but that's also the problem:

### Everything re-renders!

It's not bad with a few events in the list, but once there's a good number of them the re-render takes a huge performance toll as the `EventList` render function goes through and populates a new array of `<Event />` components.

One thing I'd like to be able to do (though assume it'll require a complete restructuring of the application) is to be able to utilize `shouldComponentUpdate` within the `<Event />` component.

However, with my current relationship I can't do this. If you take a look at the default params for `shouldComponentUpdate`:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {...},
```

You'll notice that at the `<Event />` level, `this.props` will always equal `nextProps`, so trying to do something like:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.props !== nextProps; 
},
```

will always return `false` because at this point in the flow of things they are pointing to the exact same set of data. `nextState` of course does not exist at the `<Event />` level.

So my question is, what do I need to do to get rid of the terribly costly re-render at the `<EventList />` level?

Comment: I'm not sure how your `update` of the state actually works. But the idea of these immutability helpers is that you create a whole new object instead of updating in-place. As a result, your Event props will *not* be the same object anymore, and shouldComponentUpdate can work with the simple reference comparison. If you cannot make that work, you need to do a "deep compare" yourself (which is probably not much better than just re-rendering).

Comment: Re: "terribly costly re-render". Is it, really? You are only re-rendering the Virtual DOM. It still does a diff against the previous version before actually going to the real DOM (and updating the real DOM should also be "incremental"). I am not saying, you should not investigate "PureRender" (you should), but maybe it's not quite such a big problem yet.

Comment: I agree with @Thilo - why is this a "costly re-render" ?  Have you used the perf utils in react to actually time how long this takes you in a production environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your update call.  Currently, you essentially do `var newState = title`.  You need to actually update the top level state key.

```
_handleChange: function (id, title) {
    var update = {};
    update[id] = {title: {$set: title}};
    var newEvents = React.addons.update(this.state.events, update);

    this.setState({events: newEvents});
},
```

Or with ES6 you can avoid the local variable:

```
_handleChange: function (id, title) {
    var newEvents = React.addons.update(this.state.events, {
        [id]: {
            title: {$set: title}
        }
    });

    this.setState({events: newEvents});
},
```